# Too many audits when skipping Suggested Edits reviews?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review-audits

I see a lot of audits in the SO Suggested Edit review queue.  In the last hour I've rejected 6 items, of which 3 were review audits.  I guess I skip a lot of items - does that mean I see more reviews per non-skip action?

Comment: Yes indeed. Without skipping anything, one can see 20 items top in one day, so suppose the chance for audit is 10% it means 2 audits in average. If you also skip, say 20 items, it means you got total of 40 items and 4 audits in average. Etc. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably.

There's an element of chance to whether or not you get an audit when the system goes to find something for you to review. "Skip" spins the wheel again, giving you another shot at the Markov jackpot.

Comment: Wooo! I can keep using the machine without putting additional coins in!

Comment: I feel like I'm inching towards my Steward badge without actually doing much.

Comment: Well, sooner or later your luck will run out and you'll end up with a string of real edits.

Comment: @Shog9 Question: suppose that on a low traffic site I have 5 "first answer" questions pending. Now suppose that I get an audit. Would I still see **5** as the number of item to review afterwards? To be clearer: if there are 5 item to review, does trigger an audit "consume" one of the item?

Comment: No, @SPArchaeologist.

Comment: @Shog9 Doesn't this mean that Mr. Evil Reviewer can detect audit just by looking at the number of item left for review? If the number does not decrease, the current item should be an audit (or at least there is a good probability that it is)

Comment: The number doesn't go down until after you complete the review, @SPArchaeologist.